# Missing rows while exporting more than 1 milliion record into csv file via SSIS

Tags: ssis

Task : Need to export 1.1 million records to a csv file

I loaded it via SSIS Dataflow. [image]

As you can see there are 1,100,800 rows that is loaded from a table(Source) to the FlatFile location which is a CSV file.

My FlatFile destination Source filename is Test.csv 
Now when i open the csv file i get the error

"file not loaded completely"

[image]

Now when i see the record at the very end of my csv file .Sorry cannot attache the csv file due to data integrity.
[image]

So i only see record till 1048578 but the row i loaded was 1,100880 so there are some missing rows and i cannot add them manually as well . See the end of the csv it does not let me type to the next row. 
Any idea why?

As for workaround i loaded in to seperate csv file 1 million in 1 csv and rest in others. 
But i really wanna know why it is doing this. 
Thank you in advance for looking at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Excel's fault. It only supports 1,048,576 rows.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

The error you're getting is because you're trying to open a .csv with more than the acceptable number of rows. Try opening the file in a different app, like Notepad++.

Comment: Wow , thanks a lot i have been banging my head even wrote a C# code to dump data in csv as well as merge file via SSIS process task .. Who new microsoft products have defects . Need to log a bug in there name. I have bugs flying in saying csv file does not have 1.1 million record . QA's  ???

Comment: I am sorry the answer you provided are limitation regarding Excel , but i am dealing with CSV file format.

Comment: But you're trying to open the file in Excel. Excel is limited in the number of rows in can handle. Try opening your .csv in another app. Personally, I'd try it with Notepad++.

Comment: I guess its how you open the file. If you open as excel limitation kicks in but if you open as txt you will see more than 1048578  rows . Thanks for the info appreciated .